# How to compare two check box values on android?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android, please help me.

How can I accomplish that a value gets printed, if both check boxes in the following code are enabled?

```
public EditText output;
Button one;

int a;
CheckBox check,check1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    output =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    one=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    check  = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
    check1 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);

    check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {
                    //is chkIos checked?
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                a=100;

            }
            else{
                a=0;
            }
               }
                      });

    check1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {
                    //is chkIos checked?
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                a=100;
            }
            else{
                a=0;
            }
          }
});


//this statment is wrong.    if((check.isChecked() == true)&&(check.isChecked() == true)){

        a=200;
    }

 one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  

       public void onClick(View v) {                 
            if(v==one){
              output.setText(""+a);
            }
       }
});
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the onClick method of the button

```
if((checkBox1.isChecked()) && (checkBox2.isChecked)){
     editText.setText("Both are checked");
}
```

We will not need to assign any variables as isChecked method returns a boolean and hence can be checked directly inside if.

Comment: Have you removed implementation for the setOnClickListener() you called on your check boxes. Can you also post the changes you have made?

Comment: (R.id.checkbox1);
   check1 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
  
   one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v)
       {
     if(check.isChecked()){a=100;}
     else{a=0;}
     if(check1.isChecked()){a=100;}
     else{a=0;}
            
            if(check.isChecked()&& check1.isChecked())
            {
             a=200;
            }
            else{a=0;}
            if(v==one)
            {
             output.setText(""+a);
             }
           
       }});
this is my new code

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkbox_meat:
            if (checked)
                // Put some meat on the sandwich
            else
                // Remove the meat
            break;
        case R.id.checkbox_cheese:
            if (checked)
                // Cheese me
            else
                // I'm lactose intolerant
            break;
        // TODO: Veggie sandwich
    }
}
```

Comment: if both checkbox_meat and checkbox_cheese are checked i need some action to be preformed, can u pls help me in that.

Comment: Can you please tell me what action you need to be doing in there? And with what part of implementation do you need help?

Answer (score 0):

Declare two checkbox as final and compare with

```
if (check.isChecked() == true && check1.isChecked == true)
```

In my case it works. Example: Check the status of the checkbox in OnClick method of the button

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final CheckBox check = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check);
    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {
              Log.d("Tag-test", "Value:" + check.isChecked());
          }
    });
}
```

Comment: this is not wroking as
if check.isChecked () {// comments}
donot return any value.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is my new code

public EditText output;
Button one;

int a;
CheckBox check,check1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
output =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    one=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     check  = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
     check1 = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);

     one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
             if(check.isChecked()){a=100;}
             else{a=0;}
             if(check1.isChecked()){a=100;}
             else{a=0;}

              if(check.isChecked()&& check1.isChecked())
              {
                  a=200;
              }
              else{a=0;}
              if(v==one)
              {
                  output.setText(""+a);
                  }

         }});
```

Comment: here if(check.isChecked()&& check1.isChecked()) working fine but if(check.isChecked()){a=100;}
             else{a=0;}
             if(check1.isChecked()){a=100;}
             else{a=0;}
giving value 0